# How can I change a button's icon when clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, font-awesome

I tried the below code but is not showing the 'fa-xmark' rather it's showing the 'fa-bars'.

I want 'fa-xmark to show when I click on the 'fa-bars'

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.toggle_btn')
const toggleBtnIcon = document.querySelector('.toggle_btn i')
const dropDownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu')

toggleBtn.onclick = function() {
  dropDownMenu.classList.toggle('open')
  const isOpen = dropDownMenu.classList.contains('open')

  toggleBtnIcon.classList = isOpen ?
    'fa-solid fa-xmark' :
    'fa-solid fa-bars'
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<a href="#" class="sign_btn">Signup</a>

 <div class="toggle_btn">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>

<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="hero">Home</a></li>

  <li><a href="hero">Task</a></li>

  <li><a href="hero">File</a></li>

  <li><a href="hero">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="sign_btn">Signup</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the code for `toggle_btn` and the `i` icon?  See [mcve].

Comment: Your list markup is invalid. List items must be direct descendants of a list element.

Comment: Please revise the snippet demo above to show the problem. See [ask] and take the [tour] for important tips.

Comment: Unsolicited advice: The verb form of the noun "signup" is "sign up". It should be two words. You'd use "signup" as a noun for phrasing like "... on the signup page".

Comment: I think `classList` is readonly (per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList_)), so you can't just set the class name with that. You could toggle each of those class names OR set it via `className`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: *I want 'fa-xmark to show when I click on the 'fa-bars'* - this appears to be exactly what your (updated) snippet is now doing.  What's the issue and can you provide code to *demonstrate* it?

Comment: The code is there below sir

Comment: You question is currently:   *"I want to do X and here's code that does X"* - what's the question?  Your code does what you've asked it to do.  *Is* there a question?

Comment: Is not working I want it to be showing X when I click on Bars(dropdown menu) but its still showing bars

Comment: When I click on "run snippet" in your question, it shows bars (3 horiz lines) - clicking on them changes to an X.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
$('.toggle_btn i').click(function() {
$(this).removeClass('old-class');
$(this).addClass('new-class');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The JS is fine (I would have used ID's instead of classes but it is alright). You just don't have the right HTML.

The error says that it does not find an object with the class "toggleBtn".

Here, use this HTML:

```
  <button class="toggle_btn">
      <i><img src="test.jpg"></img></i> 
  </button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cdntp7kf/1/

Comment: We can assume that there's a button present, but which wasn't shown to us here. This is why I asked for improvement to the question.

Comment: The missing element error is because OP didn't provide all the code.  It could be *simply* that they don't have a valid button or the `<i>` for the icon is not in the right place (given the noted incorrect `li`)